# Multipeer Connectivity Framework

Tags: ios, session, multipeer-connectivity

My question is very simple, and is related to the Multipeer Connectivity Framework in iOS.
O know that I can have multiple sessions running on my device. However, suppose a case in which I have three devices (A, B, and C). Can I connect device A to B and then connect B to C ? I think my quesiton is: Can I have have multiple sessions even as a peer ? For instance, in my previous example, device B is connected to device A and at the same time is connected to device C. This means that device B is a peer connected to a session with device A and also has its own session and establishes a connection with device C.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it? :) It is possible and shouldn't be that hard to implement.

Comment: @Losiowaty I haven't tried it because I dont have a macbook or an iphone. I am asking first because I tried to do that using Android, and their Wifi-Direct's implementation does not support this feature ( not without rooting the device). So I decided to ask before doing any purchase.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes, you can do this. I have an app in the store that does just that connects individual sessions to services on different devices but to me, your question is still missing details in order to be certain. Are you talking about relay on the same service (meshing) or are you talking about unique services on A and C and B wants both?

Comment: @BradBrighton I am talking about something like a mesh, in which I have some peers connected with each other and sharing files, such as videos and musics.

Comment: MPC is mesh networking at its core. Get your free developer account at Apple and watch this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/enterprise/#15 (if somehow the link isn't what I think, look for the WWDC video "Nearby Networking with Multipeer Connectivity").